# When we create a KeyStore in android app with KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder, Can that key is accessible to rooted device or where that key is stored?

Tags: android, android-keystore

I'm using KeyStore to encrypt the user name and password in my app,
i'm concerned about the key generated by KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder,is accessible to rooted device or where that key is stored in the app ?

I'm refering to this link.

[how to use KeyStore](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#WhichShouldIUse)

Comment: On rooted everything on the device is available. Your app can be reverse-engineered to extract the key from it.

Comment: @FlorianBarth even if the device has a secure hardware trusted execution environment?